# User defined transformer in Pyspark pipeline

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create a pyspark pipeline to run a classification model. My dataset has a column which is a string. So I am using 'StringIndexer' to convert it to numeric before applying a model in pipeline.

My pipeline contains just 2 stages *StringIndexer* and *ClassificationModel*

StringIndexer is creating a new column with index, however old column is also retained. I want to introduce a new transformer in pipeline to drop a 'string' column. Is this possible ?

Is there any other way to drop the actual columns in *StringIndexer*?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can extends the `abstract class Transformer` and create your own transformer which drop the unnecessary columns.

This should look something like the following :

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.Transformer
import org.apache.spark.ml.param.ParamMap
import org.apache.spark.ml.util.Identifiable
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Dataset}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{
  ArrayType,
  StringType,
  StructField,
  StructType
}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.collect_list

class Dropper(override val uid: String) extends Transformer {

  def this() = this(Identifiable.randomUID("dropper"))

  override def transform(dataset: Dataset[_]): DataFrame = {
    dataset.drop("your-column-name-here")
  }

  override def copy(extra: ParamMap): Transformer = defaultCopy(extra)

  override def transformSchema(schema: StructType): StructType = {
    //here you should right your result schema i.e. the schema without the dropped column
  }

}
```

I've been doing that for a while and it works for me just fine.

Note that you can also extends the `abstract class Estimator`.

Hope it helps. Best Regards

Comment: @Deva please make the answer as correct if it works fine, otherwise comment your problems